# Refusing because php8.0 could cause an invalid combination

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation

> Error raised while trying to upgrade/update php version to 8.0 on
> amazon linux 2 (AWS ec2) Following the below procedure could raise
> error "Refusing because php8.0 could cause an invalid combination."

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
sudo  amazon-linux-extras | grep php
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4
sudo yum install php php7.4-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}
```

eg:

```
# amazon-linux-extras enable php8.0
```

Refusing because php8.0 could cause an invalid combination.

**Try the below steps to solve this**
//Remove the php

Answer (score 19):

```
#yum remove -y php php-* \ 

#sudo amazon-linux-extras disable php7.2
```

(whichever is the version enabled)

Run

```
#amazon-linux-extras list | grep php
```

to list *available* and *disalbe* all shows **enabled**

```
 15  php7.2                          available    \
 17  **lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2=latest  enabled**      \
  _  php7.3                          available    \
  _  php7.4                          available    [ =stable ]
  _  php8.0                          available    [ =stable ]
```

We might find something like the one highlighted in bold and disable that too
eg: `sudo amazon-linux-extras disable lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2` in the above case.

Once above steps are done try running

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4
sudo yum install php php7.4-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}
```

Once we are done with installation verify

```
php -v
```

which will give an output similar to the one below

```
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2021 17:35:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This was the only method which worked for me to install PHP 8.0 on AWS EC2 Linux AMI 2. However, I had to change this line


`sudo yum install php php7.4-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}`


to


`sudo yum install php-{pear,cgi,pdo,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip}`